# How do I replace non-alphanumeric chacters only at the beginning/endn of a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.7.  I have the following for replacing non-alphanumeric characters in a word (applying the function to an array of strings) ...

```
words = map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x), long_words)
```

How would I modify the above so that only alpha-numeric characters are replaced at the beginning and end of a word?  That is, a word in the array that looked like

```
($abc-fff%%-)
```

would become

```
 abc-fff
```

Right now, its turning into

```
 abcfff
```

Comment: What if input is `_abc_` ?

Comment: I feel like in this case you would be better off without `regex` in terms of speed. For such a simple operation just iterate and use `not x.isalpha()` on the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `^` and `$` to match the start/end of a string:

```
print(re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', '($abc-fff%%-)'))
```

Output:

```
abc-fff
```